# How to convert stored database utc timestamps data into local timezone in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

is there any chance to convert database utc zone timestamps record into local timezone in PHP?

```
//example of code

$utc_date = $row['utc_date'];
```

Comment: You can use `date_default_timezone_set('your-local-time-zone-here');`

Comment: still doesnt change anything. i mean, i have stored data in database, the date is **timestamps** data type and the timezone is utc. i wanna get the record in the php and convert it into my local time zone

Comment: Kindly check updated added an answer solution in

Answer (score 0):

```
// common values
$timezone = "Australia/Melbourne";
$tz  = new DateTimeZone($timezone);
$dt = new DateTime();
$dt->setTimezone($tz);

// this can run inside a loop or by itself
$utc_date = $row['utc_date'];
$dt->setTimestamp(strtotime($utc_date));
$datetime = $dt->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
// use the formatted date as required
echo $datetime;
```

You can create a new DateTime object inside a loop if you prefer or create it outside the loop and reuse it.

If the date/times don't come out of the database in the format `2019-07-18 10:00:00+00:00` you may have to add `+00:00` to the retreived date.

Answer (score 0):

You can simple use following exmaple to resolve your problem

```
<?php
//Conside in UTC the date and time will be looks like this
$utcTime = time(); 
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $utcTime);

//now change it to your time zone
date_default_timezone_set('Your-local-time-zone');
$utc_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($row['utc_date']));
?>
```

Let Say for my time zone I'll use

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
```

Also, You can find your timezone supported by `PHP` or not [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php)

You can read more about `PHP Date` funcation from [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Comment: What happens when the time retrieved from the database was inserted as UTC time and the database server and the webserver the scripts is running on are already on 'Asia/Kolkata' time?

Comment: In that case the above solution will output prefectly. Even if my default timezone is `Asia/Kolkata` and I'm using the same timezone funcation nothing will change.